# Laravel cannot seem to yield a section

Tags: php, laravel

Having a bit of a brain fart. Can't figure out why my section is not being included

So I'm trying to include the section `scripts` in  my footer, but I get nothing when I reload the page. It is definitely being loaded, just the yield is not working

So here's my **view**:

```
@extends('layouts/form')

@section('scripts')
    <script>
        alert('It works!');
    </script>
@stop
```

Here is **layouts/form**

```
@include('layouts/head')
@include('layouts/header')

// html stuff

@include('layouts/footer')
```

And my **footer**:

```
// footer html
@yield('scripts','')
</body>
</html>
```

Is my understanding of sections correct? If the section `scripts` does not exist then it simply prints out nothing. Does it need to be in a certain order?

Comment: Your exact code works for me here... what have you called these files?  do they use the `"<filename>.blade.php"` pattern?  Normally the blade templating engine uses the dot syntax, rather than a slash to identify the templates: `@extends('layouts.form')` rather than `@extends('layouts/form')`.. but both work here.. are you on Windows?

Comment: What view are you returning as a response from your route/controller action? It should be `return View::make('your_view');` where `your_view` is the one begining with `@extends('layouts/form')`. (also that code works for me as well).

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the `blade template engine`:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  @yield('content')
</div>
```

Is valid, and anything that extends the file containing this @yield (in my case `master.blade.php`) will print it's content there:

```
@section('content')
  <div class="container-fluid">
    @include("order-form")
  </div>
@stop
```

The only other thing I can think of (after getting a `@yield('scripts')` to work flawlessly on one of my projects is the structure. To give you an idea, this is my structure for app/views:

```
..
-> forms
   -> generic.blade.php
   -> loss.blade.php
   -> rts.blade.php
-> layouts
   -> master.blade.php
index.blade.php
order.blade.php
```

`layouts.master -> @yield('content') ->  index.blade.php -> @section('content') -> @include('forms.loss') -> @stop`

That should make the relationships pretty clear.. Maybe that helps, I dunno. It's tricky, and I feel like it should work in your case. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: No luck, it's really odd. Doesn't work if I try yield another section either. I am doing the same thing on the back end of the website except it's in the head and that works fine

Comment: Hmm... Very odd indeed. And these are `file.blade.php` like msturdy asked?

Answer (score 0):

It was actually because I am have some pages being loaded from a database which tells laravel which layout to use, so the script section was never in them that view